# Storing user profile fields and information in a scalable and extensible way

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, schema, database-schema

I am working on a social networking website focusing on a specific niche, and I had a question about storing user profile information. While I want users to be able to store information such as Gender, Occupation, Likes, Dislikes, etc. I also want to do it in such a way where, if I wanted to add any more profile fields in the future, I could do so easily and possibly even through an administrative interface.

Here is the database schema I have constructed so far:

**Users**

- id (PK)
- email
- password (etc...)

**ProfileFields** (this would store fields such as "Gender", "Occupation", as well as what type of input to expect: text, list, checkboxes, radio buttons, etc.)

- id (PK)
- field_label
- is_optional
- value_type (enum: text, textarea, list, dropdown, checkbox, radio)
- is_multiple_allowed (valid only for list, really)

**ProfileFields_Presets** (this would store the preset selectable values for any given ProfileFields entry, for which there will entries only if the *value_type* is list, dropdown, checkbox, or radio)

- id (PK)
- guid (for HTML element IDs, etc.)
- profile_field_id (FK: ProfileFields)
- sort_order
- field_preset (e.g. "Male", "Female" for Gender)

**User_ProfileFields** (this would store user input for various ProfileFields entries)

- user_id (PK, FK: Users)
- profile_field_id (PK, FK: ProfileFields)
- user_value (whatever the user entered; this would be an FK:ProfileFields_Values or text that the user typed in)

Profile fields such as "Gender" — which have preset values that the user can select — will implement the ProfileFields_Values database (to store the preset values), whereas fields such as "Occupation" — which are generally open-ended — will not.

Basically, I'm just wondering if this is sufficient. Are there are any problems that might crop up as a result of doing it this way?

Also, which would be more efficient in the Users_ProfileFields table above? Having just one *user_value* field that can store either a foreign key ID or custom input? Or separating them into *user_value_id* and *user_value_text*, where one of the two will always be empty, while the other is populated with data?

Comment: Read about the limitations and performance implications of EAV tables as well as the diffiuclty doing reporting querying and other complex sql. You should use correct relational tables for as much as you can design up front.  EAV should only rarely be used when there is genuine need for the flexibility. Don't go down the EAV route in a relationsal database, if you must use it, consider a nosql db.

Comment: Hmm... what about this... instead of a ProfileFields_Presets table, I include a comma-delimited list of presets in a field in the ProfileFields table? Would that be a better way to go about doing it?

Comment: No, comma delimited lists are even worse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave it as it is.  I would separate to user_value_id and then user_value_text.  With User_value_id being a key